# How do I represent an Array of objects in a class diagram

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, uml, class-diagram

I have this product model product model:

```
variations: [ 
  {
    name: { type: String }, 
    price: { type: Number }
  }
],
options: [
  {
    name: { type: String }, 
    price: { type: Number }
  }
]
```

And I want to represent those array of objects in my class diagram but I'm sure how to exactly this is the class diagram for product:

[image]

I was thinking about options : `Object []` but I don't think that is correct

Comment: I'd just make a sub-block of a different colour (like maybe a darker blue) with the same structure as your pre-existing light blue block. Consistency is key with documentation, so making it consistent to have nested sub-objects is a very good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields `options` and `variations` are arrays of objects that share some common features (e.g. they all have a `name` and a `price` property).

In UML your design could therefore be represented with association between `Product` and two a different classes `Option` and `Variation` with a multiplicity of `*` (which means that there can be several instances of `Option`/`Variation` associated with one instance of `Product`):

[image]

(*Btw: in native UML, Number would be Real, but we can assume that you use a JS profile that adds to the UML built-in types language specific types*)

Alternatively, you can represent your design using two properties with the right multiplicity between square brackets.  According to the UML semantics, both notations (association with a class and property of a given class) are almost the same:

[image]

Of course, you could make the shortcut and not define classes for `Option` and `Variation`, and use `Object` instead.  But this does not represent accurately your model in UML, since nothing would tell that the objets in those arrays are guaranteed to have a `name` and a `price`.

*P.S: qwerty_so drew my attention at the other `String []` in your diagram, which should indeed be `String[*]` in UML syntax. In the same spirit, whenever needed, `String[1..*]` could be used to mean "at least one string but more are possible"*

Comment: You could also make a note about his `String` vs. `String[]` notation.

Comment: @qwerty_so Thank you, I didn't spot those.  I edited accordingly.